# Why does QGIS ignore letter or word spacing in exports?

Tags: qgis, labeling, print-composer

My line label have letter spacing of 3px (Layer Properties -> Labels -> Text -> Spacing -> Letter). In print composer everything is drawn like I want it but after export to svg, pdf, or image the letter spacing is simply ignored; the label is drawn without any spacing.

Is that a known issue? Is it a bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: My tests confirm your observations. So, I think you better report this issue at http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues

Comment: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/9792

Answer (score 1):

This was an issue in QGIS 2.2 http://hub.qgis.org/issues/9792 and should be fixed now.